# Error :Unable to open trace file '/mnt/sdcard/method.trace': Permission denied in android 3.0

Tags: android

I am facing problem while creating trace file using

```
Debug.startMethodTracing("traceFile");
```

I have also added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in manifest file
But when I am trying to run the application I am getting this error

```
01-13 10:53:32.739: D/dalvikvm(1261): +++ active profiler count now 1
01-13 10:53:32.739: I/dalvikvm(1261): TRACE STARTED: '/mnt/sdcard/traceFile.trace' 8192KB
01-13 10:53:32.739: E/dalvikvm(1261): Unable to open trace file '/mnt/sdcard/traceFile.trace': Permission denied
01-13 10:53:32.739: D/dalvikvm(1261): +++ active profiler count now 0
01-13 10:53:32.950: D/AndroidRuntime(1261): Shutting down VM
01-13 10:53:32.950: W/dalvikvm(1261): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sample.internetTV/com.sample.internetTV.Internet_TV4}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open trace file '/mnt/sdcard/traceFile.trace': Permission denied
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1736)
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open trace file '/mnt/sdcard/traceFile.trace': Permission denied
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at dalvik.system.VMDebug.startMethodTracingNative(Native Method)
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at dalvik.system.VMDebug.startMethodTracing(VMDebug.java:175)
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at android.os.Debug.startMethodTracing(Debug.java:458)
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at android.os.Debug.startMethodTracing(Debug.java:406)
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at com.sample.internetTV.Internet_TV4.onCreate(Internet_TV4.java:37)
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
01-13 10:53:33.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):     ... 11 more
```

This was working fine in Android 2.2 version. But In Android 3.0 I am getting error
So can anybody please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you've memory allocated for your Android 3.0 emulator?

Comment: @Ghost Thanks for Reply. Is there any requirement to allocate memory for Android 3.0 emulator while creating trace file? It was not required to do that while creating trace file on Android 2.2 emulator. If it is required then how can we do this?

Comment: I'm not really sure if it should be done or even if I'm right in my speculation. That's why commenting here rather than answering. Since you're "writing external storage", I reckoned you should be emulating an SD card like this: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#sdcard